# AWS EC2 - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, jdbc, amazon-ec2

After moving the server-side of my client-server application to an amazon EC2 instance (ubuntu 64but) I started getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

```
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
```

when trying to create a new JDBC connection. My server code is:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("host", "username", "password"); //crashes here
```

I downloaded the `apt-get install libmysql-java` and now my `/usr/share/java/` dir on the server looks like this:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  30530 Dec  9  2013 java-atk-wrapper.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    948 Mar 22  2014 java_defaults.mk
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   2615 Apr 28  2014 libintl.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 915836 Jan  1  2014 mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     31 Jan  1  2014 mysql-connector-java.jar -> mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     24 Jan  1  2014 mysql.jar -> mysql-connector-java.jar
```

any clue what might be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely explaination is that when you moved from one server to another there was a class path setting that needed adjusting

Ensure that `/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar` is in the class path for the application that is giving the error

Comment: Can I not just export the `connector` as part of my jar from my IDE options? I am using IntelliJ.

Comment: I can't explain it in any more basic terms than I already have, sorry